# Partition scan order in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, partitioning, postgresql-performance

I have created a natively partitioned table in Postgres and when trying to query this, Postgres is scanning the partitions in ascending order. The partition key is a timestamp column. For my use case, the application has more probability of finding the row in the recent tables, thus I want Postgres to scan the partitions in descending order, but I am not able to find a way to make this happen.

Sample table that I have tried this on:

```
create table test (id varchar(255), value varchar(255), date timestamp with time zone) partition by range(date);

create table test_202205 partition of test for values from ('2022-05-01') to ('2022-06-01');

create table test_202206 partition of test for values from ('2022-06-01') to ('2022-07-01');

create table test_202207 partition of test for values from ('2022-07-01') to ('2022-08-01');

insert into test values('aa','foo',now()); //Goes to June table

explain analyse select * from test where value = 'foo' order by date desc;


                                                     QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=32.66..32.67 rows=3 width=1040) (actual time=0.024..0.025 rows=0 loops=1)
   Sort Key: test_202205.date DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..32.64 rows=3 width=1040) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on test_202205  (cost=0.00..10.88 rows=1 width=1040) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: ((value)::text = 'foo'::text)
         ->  Seq Scan on test_202206  (cost=0.00..10.88 rows=1 width=1040) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: ((value)::text = 'foo'::text)
         ->  Seq Scan on test_202207  (cost=0.00..10.88 rows=1 width=1040) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: ((value)::text = 'foo'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.099 ms
 Execution Time: 0.052 ms
(12 rows)
```

Even when trying to order the partition key in descending order, it still scans the partitions in ascending order, while I would like to scan in descending order. Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: It's due to the probability, it's over 90% chance that I will find the row in the most recent table, and over 99% that I will find it in one of the two most recent. In actual scenario, I will have 6 partitions and I don't want to waste time by scanning the first 4 partitions every time.

Comment: I am not looking to limit the scan using this, I was already able to try 'limit 1' and it did stop looking after it found a row. My question is only regarding the order in which the scan is done. Is there a way to reverse that?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't include that here as I got that working. My question is just regarding the order. Even if it scans all partitions, it is fine for me as long as I can change the order.

Comment: I am also afraid that there isn't since searching around didn't lead to anything. Hoping someone can chime in with some workaround.

Comment: Thanks, will take care of that!

Comment: This question is a mess.  If the LIMIT is there, why isn't it shown?  If it is not there, then how could it ever stop early no matter which direction it scans?

Comment: @jjanes It's not shown here because stopping early isn't something I am questioning since I already got it to work. This question concerns only the scan order, nothing else.

Comment: Also, the comment section may look messy because I was replying to someone who have deleted their comments now.

Answer (score 3):

Postgresql 12 uses [ordered partition scan](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1hCY8y-0000UA-Ov%40gemulon.postgresql.org) automatically when possible.

Let's write some data, index on date and check behaviour:

```
insert into test select 'id'||i, 'v', date '2022-08-01' - interval '10 min' * i from generate_series(1, 10000) as i;
INSERT 0 10000
create index on test (date);
CREATE INDEX
explain analyse select * from test where value = 'v' order by date desc limit 1;
                                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.84..0.89 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.030..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.84..451.86 rows=10000 width=16) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan Backward using test_202207_date_idx on test_202207 test_3  (cost=0.28..173.40 rows=4464 width=16) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)
               Filter: ((value)::text = 'v'::text)
         ->  Index Scan Backward using test_202206_date_idx on test_202206 test_2  (cost=0.28..166.90 rows=4320 width=16) (never executed)
               Filter: ((value)::text = 'v'::text)
         ->  Index Scan Backward using test_202205_date_idx on test_202205 test_1  (cost=0.28..61.56 rows=1216 width=17) (never executed)
               Filter: ((value)::text = 'v'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.556 ms
 Execution Time: 0.052 ms
```

As you can see, only one partition was actually scanned.

Comment: Hey, this is good, but is there a way to do this without indexing the date column? I will be indexing the value column on which I will actually be doing the search.

Comment: Create multicolumn index on (value, date). Planner needs presorted data to doing such optimisation.

Comment: Ah, okay. I don't have any other use for that index, will you say the added bloat is worth it? Alternatively, I am just considering implementing this in my application.